# Puppet v4 losing build-in 'ensure' parameter on File type when using puppet-xmlfile module

Tags: ruby, windows, puppet

When using the [puppet-xmlfile](https://github.com/capablue/puppet-xmlfile/tree/fix_relative_require) module on puppetserver version: 2.2.1 with a Windows 2012 R2 node with Puppet 4.3.2 I receive the following error when trying to perform a puppet run:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: no parameter named 'ensure' at 
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/my_environment/manifests/default.pp:12 
on File[C:/tmp/] at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/my_environment/manifests/default.pp:12 on node xxx
```

However it runs successfully on the first run after restarting the puppetserver. Every subsequent run fails.

Puppet manifest:

```
 $staging_windir = 'C:/tmp/'
 file { $staging_windir:
    ensure => directory,
 }

 xmlfile { "C:/Path To Existing XML File/config.xml":
    ensure            => present,
    use_existing_file => true,
 }

 xmlfile_modification { "test" :
    file       => "C:/Path To Existing XML File/config.xml",
    changes  => 'set /Someconfig/State "Enabled"',
 }
```

Using the branch "fix_relative_require" of the puppet-xmlfile module from this repo: https://github.com/capablue/puppet-xmlfile/tree/fix_relative_require

The above code is enough to re-create it, it will produce the error listed at the top of this question.

I cannot see any reason why the built-in Puppet File Type would suddenly lose it's `ensure` parameter. When I remove the xmlfile types from the manifest the File['C:/tmp/'] works fine again. Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: I agree that it seems very odd.  What version of puppet-xmlfile are you using?  Can you provide an [mcve]?

Comment: @JohnBollinger you can pull in the following branch using R10k: https://github.com/sedan07/36331512-xmlfile-param-issue make sure you restart the puppetserver afterwards because it internally caches the ruby code

Comment: That's not how it works here.  For your question to be of use to anyone else, it must be self-contained.  Moreover, cutting down the problem to the minimum code necessary to reproduce it makes it easier on the unpaid volunteers to whom you are posing your question, and sometimes that process helps you discover the problem for yourself.  So, no, I will not be pulling anything from your git repo.

Comment: The git repo does contain the minimum code necessary, that is ALL it contains (I created it and it contents just for this post). I added it to git repo to make it easier to re-create so you can just use R10k to pull it down and install the dependant module. If you prefer I can put the exact instructions on how to re-create on the ticket then you can do them manually and waste some time instead of having the heavy lifting done for you